# Unable to run custom hello world SFDX plugin locally

Tags: sfdx-plugin

I followed the instructions mentioned in the documentation: [Scaffold a Salesforce CLI Plug-In](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_generate_scaffold.htm).

After generating the boilerplate code with command: `sfdx plugins:generate hello`, I got the project as described in the documentation.

I followed below instruction to run the project-

> 4. To run the commands in your in-development plug-in from the directory that your code lives in, precede the commands with bin/run. Look at the `--help` (`-h`) output for the sample `hello:org` command.
>
>    ```
>    bin/run hello:org -h
>    ```

Mentioned command yields me an error:

```bash
$ bin/run hello:org -h
 »   Error: command hello:org not found
```

What would be the cause and how can I fix this. Please share your thoughts.

---

I see that the `hello` command works but the `hello:org` doesn't :-/

```bash
$ bin/run hello -h
Commands to say hello.

USAGE
  $ sfdx hello:COMMAND
```

I didn't make any change to created project:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of a minor bug from `sfdx plugins:generate`. In the `package.json` file, you most likely have `"commands": "./lib/commands"`, but in the custom plugin directory structure, `commands` folder is under `src` folder. Refer to the screenshots below.

[image]

Update the `package.json` (oclif > commands) to `"commands": "./src/commands"` to fix the problem.

Comment: +1 Thanks @arut, nice catch! This was definitely the problem, also noticed we can compile the typescript project as well to generate the lib output folder. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Arut pointed out this was a problem with commands not available in right folder, that is `lib`.

---

Noticed that here is a file `typescript.json`, from what I understood, typescript projects needs to be compiled first.

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@salesforce/dev-config/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

There are 2 options to generate the `lib` output as per configuration:

1. [Directly with typescript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling), install typescript globally:

   ```
   npm install -g typescript
   ```

   - When running command `tsc` in the project, it compiles the code and generates the `lib` output folder.
2. Another option is as `package.json` contains script for `prepack`.

   ```json
   "scripts": {
       "prepack": "rimraf lib && tsc -b && oclif-dev manifest && oclif-dev readme"
   ```

   - we can also run script `npm run prepack`, this also generates the `lib`.

Comment: FYI: I did perform the point # 1 earlier, but that did not make any difference in my case. Not sure if I was missing something else.

Comment: Let me delete my project and try again, so as to confirm.

Comment: Just confirming #1 worked fine, it generated the lib folder and I am able to run it locally: `bin/run hello:org`

Comment: Both the options worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to run the command is using  below command in an SFDX Project that you already have

```
sfdx hello:org
```

If you need to kick off the debugger

```
sfdx hello:org --dev-suspend
```

Comment: My bad, I am a beginner with typescript and I didn't compile the project first, hence the command was unavailable; either locally or after plugin linking.